# Laravel/Lumen PSR-4: If I put classes into subdirectories do I have to use different namespaces then?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, lumen, laravel-5.5

Look at the following part of my application structure:

```
App
-Events
-Http
--Controllers
---Rest
-Services
--Base
--Primary
```

What I would like to do is to use the namespace `App\Services` for all services and the namespace `App\Http\Controller` for all controllers.

This is how my application is loaded with Composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    } }
```

This is the Exception I get:

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Class 'App\Services\CapabilityService' not
>   found

`CapabilityService` exists for sure, but it is within the subfolder `Primary`. Is there a way to autoload files from subdirectories into one namespace together? If yes how and is there any important reason not to do it?

This is the CapabilityService:

```
namespace App\Services;
```

This is the location:

```
App/Services/Primary/CapabilityService
```

Comment: why not using `App\Services\Primary\CapabilityService` ?

Comment: What's the namespace of `CapabilityService`?

Comment: @Hamoud I think it would be easier to have a common namespace for all services. Have a look at my question edited.

Comment: @Camilo I think it would be easier to have a common namespace for all services. Have a look at my question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm I figured it out - just do arrays in within `composer.json`, where you specify all subfolders:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "App\\Services\\": ["app/services","app/services/base","app/services/primary"],
            "App\\Models\\": ["app/models","app/models/traits"],
            "App\\Http\\Controllers\\": ["app/http/controllers","app/http/controllers/base","app/http/controllers/rest","app/http/controllers/rest/base"]
        },
```

Better solutions still welcome.